# How can I import a custom action workflow in sharepoint desginer?

Tags: 2010, workflow-activity, codeplex

I've just download a custom action workflow on codeplex but I don't how to import it. It's a .wsp format file and sharepoint doesn't seem to recognize it... Is somebody know how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy wsp to the SharePoint. It will not work directly. Follow below link
 http://documentation.agilepoint.com/SupportPortal/Docs/ProductDocumentation/CurrentRelease/DocumentationLibrary/maps/installDeployWspsPowerShell.html